# how do I check if an array is empty?

Tags: java

This is my code, the output will print only the first course, I don't know what is wrong, I'd like some help :(

```
public class student {
  private long student_ID;
  private int[] listOfCourses= new int[5];
  private double[] Mark=new double[5];
  private int numCoures;  

  public student(long student_ID) {
    this.student_ID=student_ID;
  }

  long getStudentID() {
    return student_ID;
  }

  int getnumCoures(){
    return numCoures;
  }

  void addCourse(int CN) {
    for(int i=0 ; i<listOfCourses.length ; i++){
      if (listOfCourses[i]==0) {
        listOfCourses[i]=CN;  
      }
    }
    numCoures++;
  }

  void addMark(int CN,double M) {
    for(int i=0 ; i<listOfCourses.length ; i++) {
      if(listOfCourses[i]==CN) {
        Mark[i]=M;
      }
    }
  }

  void print() {
    System.out.println("NAME OF student "+student_ID);
    for(int i=0 ; i<numCoures ; i++) { 
      System.out.println("NAME OF COURSE "+listOfCourses[i]+" MARK "+Mark[i]);   
    }
  }
}
```

The main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  student S1 = new student(1000000001);
  S1.addCourse(200);
  S1.addCourse(201);
  S1.addCourse(202);
  S1.addMark(200, 100);
  S1.addMark(201, 99);
  S1.addMark(202, 98);
  student S2 = new student(1111111111);
  S2.addCourse(300);
  S2.addCourse(301);
  S2.addMark(300, 70);
  S2.addMark(301, 99);

  S1.print();
  S2.print();
}
```

**Output:**

```
NAME OF student 1000000001  
NAME OF COURSE 200 MARK 100.0  
NAME OF COURSE 200 MARK 100.0  
NAME OF COURSE 200 MARK 100.0  
NAME OF student 1111111111  
NAME OF COURSE 300 MARK 70.0  
NAME OF COURSE 300 MARK 70.0
```

Comment: 1. Your formatting is a nightmare. 2. You need to learn how to debug.

Comment: Try introducing `break;` after `listOfCourses[i]=CN;` in your `for` loop.

Comment: Try putting some more effort into formatting and things like names of classes, methods and variables. Your class should start with an upper case letter (`student` should be `Student`). Variables should start with a lower case letter (`Mark` should be `mark`). Methods should be camelCase (`getnumCoures()` should be `getNumCourses()`) and why is it sometimes `courses` and in other places `coures`? Remember that your style can be an indicator of the code's quality.

Comment: Apart from this, to make your life easier, I suggest you check out the many Java collections. Plain arrays can be the right choice but often a `List`, `Map` or `Set` will be a better friend.

Comment: I did this so quickly, I know all this, I was just asking about the logic, I don't have much time to see the "formatting" thanks tho.

Comment: Is this homework?

Comment: @Os the `length` property of an array never changes after the array is created. How can it indicate if an array is empty?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Your problem is your `addCourse()` method:

```
void addCourse(int CN) {
    for (int i = 0; i < listOfCourses.length; i++) {
        if (listOfCourses[i] == 0) {
            listOfCourses[i] = CN;
        }
    }
    numCoures++;
}
```

Think about what happens here. When you add the first course, the array is all `0`. Hence, the condition `listOfCourses[i] == 0` will always yield `true` and you will fill the whole array with that course number. The next time you try to add a course, the condition will always evaluate to `false`, hence nothing changes (apart from `numCoures`).

This also means that you could call `addCourse()` very often and increase `numCoures` to some ridiculous number that doesn't have any meaning anymore.

### Possible solution

An easy fix would be to actually use `numCoures` when adding a new course:

```
void addCourse(int CN) {
    if (numCoures < listOfCourses.length) {
        listOfCourses[numCoures++] = CN;
    }
}
```

Here, we first check if `numCoures` is still within the array's bounds. If so, we insert the given course number at index `numCoures`, which would be `0` the first time around and so on. With the `++` as suffix, `numCoures` will also be increased *after* it has been evaluated.

### Solution using a `HashMap`

However, I suggest you replace your plain arrays with one of the many helpful Java collections (unless this is an exercise that explicitly asks you to use plain arrays?). For example, you could go with a [`HashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html). A map associates a key with a value. This seems to fit your scenario quite well: the course number can be the key and the mark can be the value.

We would declare this as follows:

```
private HashMap<Integer, Float> courses = new HashMap<>();
```

Also, don't forget that you will need `import java.util.HashMap;` at the top of your file.

Your `addCourse()` method could then become:

```
void addCourse(int courseNum) {
    courses.put(courseNum, null);
}
```

And `addMark()` would become:

```
void addMark(int courseNum, double mark) {
    courses.replace(courseNum, mark);
}
```

If you look up `HashMap`'s `put()` and `replace()` methods, you'll notice that we could have used `put()` in `addMark()` as well, but I feel like your intent is clearer this way.

Two more methods should now be changed:

```
int getNumCourses() {
    return courses.size();
}
```

I'll leave the `print()` to you.

Also, you can now get rid of these three, as they have been replaced by our neat `HashMap`:

```
private int[] listOfCourses = new int[5]; // bye bye
private double[] Mark = new double[5]; // cya
private int numCoures; // sayounara
```

#### Benefits of using a `Map`

- A student can have more than 5 courses
- Your code becomes shorter and easier to read
- Your code also becomes less prone to error
- Changing or removing courses or grades is easily possible

### Additional notes:

You should pay more attention to the names of your classes, variables and methods. I'll point out what I noticed:

- The class `student` should be `Student` (classes should start with an upper case letter)
- The variable `Mark` should be `mark` (variables should start with a lower case letter)
- The method `getnumCoures()` should be `getNumCourses()` )(methods should be camelCase and you mistyped *courses*)
- The variable `student_ID` and the method `getStudentID()` could be simplified to `id` and `getID()` - we already know that we're dealing with a student!

Answer (score 2):

This is what gave you trouble. The first time you call, you will assign CN to all the courses from 0 to 4.

```
void addCourse(int CN){

for(int i=0 ; i<listOfCourses.length ; i++){
    if (listOfCourses[i]==0) {
    listOfCourses[i]=CN;  
    }
 }
 numCoures++; 
 }
```

Suggestion

```
void addCourse(int CN){
 if (numCoures >= 5) return; // actually, you should throw an exception here

 listOfCourses[numCoures] = CN;
 numCoures++; 
}
```

Comment: thats the output now tho :c :    
NAME OF student 1000000001

   NAME OF COURSE 0 MARK 0.0

   NAME OF COURSE 200 MARK 100.0 

   NAME OF COURSE 201 MARK 99.0    

   NAME OF student 1111111111      

   NAME OF COURSE 0 MARK 0.0       

   NAME OF COURSE 300 MARK 70.0

Comment: Yes, I fixed it so that it will assign the first course. (numCourses = 0).

Answer (score 0):

The addCourse method sets all 5 elements of listOfCourses to the value supplied in the first call. To fix this, you want to exit the loop after setting the value by using a *break* statement. Otherwise, the code marches through the entire array:

```
void addCourse(int CN) {
    for (int i = 0; i < listOfCourses.length; i++) {
        if (listOfCourses[i] == 0) {
            listOfCourses[i] = CN;
            break;
        }
    }
    numCoures++;
}
```

There are better ways to accomplish the goals of this program. What happens if a student has more than 5 courses? Look up java.util.List and java.util.Map.

Output is:

```
NAME OF student 1000000001
NAME OF COURSE 200 MARK 100.0
NAME OF COURSE 201 MARK 99.0
NAME OF COURSE 202 MARK 98.0
NAME OF student 1111111111
NAME OF COURSE 300 MARK 70.0
NAME OF COURSE 301 MARK 99.0
```